# Build an automation program/script on Windows

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, automation

I've two projects written in node and GO. If one of them gets higher load it, stops. So I've to manually restart both projects to run again. I'm thinking of a way to restart both projects every morning and evening automatically by some kind of program or code script. It would be great if I get some advice. Thanks

Comment: Windows [Task Scheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/using-the-task-scheduler) is designed for such things.

Answer (score 2):

**For windows,**

1. Prepare batch script to restart
2. and use Task Scheduler

**For linux,**

1. Prepare sh script file to restart
2. and use crontab to schedule or use jenkins to schedule